# Update Ruby from 1.9.3 to 2.0.0 on Windows 7

Tags: ruby, windows

I installed Ruby using this software:
http://rubyinstaller.org/

However, unlike rvm, I'm not sure if I can use it to update my version of Ruby.

Can I use this to update? If not, what's the best way to update Ruby on a Windows machine?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the RubyInstaller FAQ, [there is this question](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/faq#wiki-pik):

> **Q: If I install both versions, is there some graceful way of selecting which version is active at a given time (e.g., which ruby.exe is invoked, which irb.bat is called, etc.)?**
>
> A: Pik is excellent for this coordination—[check it out](https://github.com/vertiginous/pik/tree/master)

One can extend the `both` in the question to `all three` (1.8, 1.9 and 2.0), so hopefully `pik` is forward-compatible with Ruby 2.0, so give this a try.

Comment: Hi Ken Y_N, do you know what would cause this error?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19308846/updating-ruby-to-2-0-0-using-pik