# Updating Ruby to 2.0.0 using Pik

Tags: ruby, pik

[After installing pik and changing my Ruby version to 2.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598422/how-to-upgrade-ruby-to-2-0), bundler no long works properly

```
C:\Users\Me\Documents\Work Projects\Application>bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Using rake (10.1.0)
Using i18n (0.6.5)
Using minitest (4.7.5)
Using multi_json (1.8.0)
Installing atomic (1.1.14)
Gem::InstallError: The 'atomic' native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'
An error occurred while installing atomic (1.1.14), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install atomic -v '1.1.14'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Installing the devkit from [Ruby Installer](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) sort of defeats the reason why I went to the trouble of installing pik. How can I fix this, so that in the future, I can easily update ruby using pik and still have everything working?

Comment: [Does this help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17590349/1270789)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem - if you follow the instructions [listed](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit) (ie installing devkit and following their directions [they don't actually tell you to use rubyinstaller]), you'll be fine. Also make sure that during the init phase of the Devkit instructions that it doesn't miss any of your ruby installations.

A note though, it seems that pik can't specify the x64 version of 2.0.0, so you may run into problems if that's the case. In the end I had to use the rubyinstaller for the x64 version of ruby, and then ran the x64 version of the devkit.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Definitely agree with Starkers, RVM is much preferred. My Macbook died though, which is why I've been relegated to dev on my PC box. Cheers

Comment: If one of you encounter this problem, you might want to check webdevgguy's answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18291664/error-installing-atomic

Answer (score 0):

I think Josh' answer is probably right, but I actually [installed Ubuntu as a VM](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/11287/) in the end, just so I could use RVM.

[RVM](https://rvm.io/) is a thousand times better than Pik, and it installs the DevKit. It's so good it's genuinely worth installing Ubuntu just so you can use it.